# Instance of abstract class InputStream

Tags: java, input, io

InputStream class defined as-

```
 public abstract class InputStream extends Object
```

Then how System class can contain "in" object of InputStream class ?

Comment: A very, very common question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `in` is not an object, its a reference.

Its a reference to an InputStream OR a sub-class of an InputStream.  As its abstract, it can only be a sub-class.

Answer (score 2):

The `in` field defined by the `System` class doesn't need to reference a concrete implementation of `InputStream` -- as you've worked out, it can't -- it just needs to reference something that extends `InputStream`.

On Linux at least, `in` references a BufferedInputStream that itself wraps a FileInputStream. Other implementations may vary and that's the point: the use of an abstract class like InputStream allows the implementing class to vary and potentially be changed from one version of Java to the next whilst keeping calling code happy.

Answer (score 1):

An `InputStream` is the abstract, but the concrete class (the one actually referenced by `System.in`) can be any *subclass* of InputStream, including an [anonymous class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Some subclasses listed in the [javadoc for `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) include:

- AudioInputStream
- ByteArrayInputStream
- FileInputStream
- FilterInputStream
- InputStream (CORBA)
- ObjectInputStream
- PipedInputStream
- SequenceInputStream
- StringBufferInputStream

Executing this code to find out which subclass System.in actual is:

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

Yields this answer:

```
class java.io.BufferedInputStream
```

Comment: I would also point out that `in` is not an object, but a reference.